# Failure to parse a CREATE FUNCTION Sql statement in ANTLR C#

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, antlr4

I have noticed that when I pass a (valid) CREATE FUNCTION statement to TSqlParser my listener receives a call to  `EnterCreate_or_alter_procedure()`

I am using the latest versions of TSqlLexer.g4 & TSqlParser.g4.

My output also shows

```
Exception thrown: 'Antlr4.Runtime.InputMismatchException' in Antlr4.Runtime.dll
line 1:7 mismatched input 'FUNCTION' expecting {'OR', 'PROC', 'PROCEDURE'}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: The `create_or_alter_function` rule probably couldn't be matched and then tried to use `create_or_alter_procedure` instead. Please edit your question and add enough code (and example input!) to it so that others can reproduce what you describe.

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue.

It was a copy-paste error from a previous project in which I was only interested in Stored Procedures, hence, I was passing a StoredProcedure context to the walker, not `batch()`.